# Bootstrap 3.3.7 dropdown only one link clickable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I open up the dropdown menu, only the `Home` tab is clickable. The rest act like regular text...

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
      <li class="aktivan"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Cakes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Muffins</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Coffee</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Orders</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Working fine for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `href="#"` from the `dropdown-toggle` should fix it

> To keep URLs intact with link buttons, use the data-target attribute instead of href="#"
>   [dropdowns via data attributes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#dropdowns)

I believe the `href` attribute is assigning the target `#` for the dropdown causing it not to work.